# Remote Desktop/access from a ppp connection

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, ppp

I have setup a ppp connection through a serial port between two computers with a null modem using these [instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305621). My Question is how would I remote desktop or access the host computer via the ppp connection? Is this possible?

Comment: Isn't PPP going to be very slow for RDP? Are you sure you can't use an Ethernet cable?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I agree RDP would not likely be the appropriate approach for a serial line, but there must be some way to remotely access the machine such as ssh... I am looking at this for a possible solution to change a few scripts remotely if need be.

Comment: If the other machine shows up (as I expect it should) in Windows Explorer under Network, you should be able to right click it's icon and choose "Connect with Remote Desktop Connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [SSH service for Windows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/)

Some versions of Windows have a [telnet service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299942) you can enable.